# Unable to browse my android phone via KDE connect in KDE Neon

Tags: kde-neon, kde-connect

I am on KDE Neon 5.14. Using latest versions of KDE connect on Neon and Android.
I am trying to browse my phone file system but getting this error:

`The process for the kdeconnect://92e92185f23aaf5b protocol died unexpectedly`

I have made sure KDE connect on android has all permissions and plugin is enabled on both sides.

Here is the output of `~/.xsession-errors` when trying this.

```
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kio_kdeconnect.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kio_kdeconnect.so'
QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name =  path =  pid = 13797
KCrash: Arguments: kdeinit5: PID 13797 terminated.
Could not find service for job "Job 13" with app name "org.kde.kdeconnectd"
Could not find service for job "Job 13" with app name "org.kde.kdeconnectd"
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60266, resource id: 100663303, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60267, resource id: 83886155, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60271, resource id: 83886155, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
trying to show an empty dialog
trying to show an empty dialog
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60701, resource id: 83886155, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60702, resource id: 83886161, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60703, resource id: 83886173, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60704, resource id: 83886155, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60705, resource id: 83886161, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 60706, resource id: 83886173, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 3
```

Output of `journalctl -xe` at the time:

```
Oct 21 16:07:22 neon org.kde.kdeconnect[975]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Mount device: "Xiaomi Redmi 4X"
Oct 21 16:07:23 neon org.kde.kdeconnect[975]: kf5.kio.widgets: KRun(0x55e19f43e5d0) ERROR 143 "The process for the kdeconnect://92e92185f23aaf5b protocol died unexpectedly."
Oct 21 16:07:25 neon org.kde.kdeconnect[975]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 9418, resource id: 42156835, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update: Bug fixed

With KDE Connect version 1.3.3, the problem described in this question has been solved. This version has arrived in the Neon User Edition package repositories, so you should be able to update and have no new problems!

[Here is the link to the commit which fixes this issue](https://cgit.kde.org/kdeconnect-kde.git/commit/?id=560e8638e8ddc06a92f207fb21d5e8741ec608b7)

#### Answer:

There is a bug with KDE Connect on Neon >= 5.14.1 which is preventing mounting and browsing the phone file system via KIO, which is what Dolphin uses

The bug report is [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=400178). At this point, it's pretty certainly narrowed down to Neon 5.14.1, so no need to add a "+1" unless you have new information to add, but feel free to add yourself to the subscribers list and you will be alerted when it is fixed.

As a workaround, you can manually mount the phone using kdeconnect's DBus interface, then browse it on the command line or by manually copying the path. The instructions are in the bug report, but also copied here:

Do

```
qdbus org.kde.kdeconnect /modules/kdeconnect/devices/<deviceID>/sftp mountAndWait
qdbus org.kde.kdeconnect /modules/kdeconnect/devices/<deviceID>/sftp getDirectories
```

(Feel free to substitute a different dbus browser if you don't like qdbus)

You can get your device ID by running `kdeconnect-cli --list-devices`

The first command should return true and the second command should print out a list of mounted locations. Copy/paste those locations into your file brower's address bar and you should be good to go.

Comment: from where can I get deviceID?

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds Oops! My mistake. I have added that bit to the answer. But most importantly, note that you should be able to update KDE Connect to 1.3.3 and this bug is fixed!

Comment: yup, yesterday's update fixed the bug, I was curious in your answer because it maybe helpful in future if the same bug occurs again or if I want cmd interface :-) thanks!

Comment: thanks again man, I need this answer again and again, even today

Answer (score 2):

You need kdeconnect >= 1.3.3 to solve permanently this issue.

1. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. Check your kdeconnect version:

   ```
   kdeconnect-cli --version
   ```
3. If kdeconnect version is < 1.3.3, add this repository https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/ppa:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/ppa
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
4. Reboot or restart the daemon:

   ```
   killall kdeconnectd
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd &
   ```

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your excellent explanation.